# How to count string occurrence in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I count the number of times a particular string occurs in another string. For example, this is what I am trying to do in Javascript:

```
var temp = "This is a string.";
alert(temp.count("is")); //should output '2'
```

Comment: It depends on whether you accept *overlapping* instances, e.g. var t = "sss"; How many instances of the substring "ss" are in the string above? 1 or 2? Do you leapfrog over each instance, or move the pointer character-by-character, looking for the substring?

Comment: An improved benchmark for this question's answers: http://jsperf.com/string-ocurrence-split-vs-match/2 (based of Kazzkiq's benchmark).

Comment: Count Total Amount Of Specific Word In a String JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036248/4752258

Comment: this video seems vaguely related here - "Google Coding Interview With A Facebook Software Engineer" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIeiiceWe_w

Answer (score 1390, accepted):

The `g` in the regular expression (short for *global*) says to search the whole string rather than just find the first occurrence. This matches `is` twice:

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";
var count = (temp.match(/is/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

And, if there are no matches, it returns `0`:

```js
var temp = "Hello World!";
var count = (temp.match(/is/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I went with `count = (str.match(/is/g) || []).length` to handle if you don't have a match.

Comment: Just to let you know: if you want to search using special characters, you have to escape them. For example: looking for how many '.' are, just use (text.match(/\./g) || []).length

Answer (score 279):

```
/** Function that count occurrences of a substring in a string;
 * @param {String} string               The string
 * @param {String} subString            The sub string to search for
 * @param {Boolean} [allowOverlapping]  Optional. (Default:false)
 *
 * @author Vitim.us https://gist.github.com/victornpb/7736865
 * @see Unit Test https://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/5axuh96u/
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924240/938822
 */
function occurrences(string, subString, allowOverlapping) {

    string += "";
    subString += "";
    if (subString.length <= 0) return (string.length + 1);

    var n = 0,
        pos = 0,
        step = allowOverlapping ? 1 : subString.length;

    while (true) {
        pos = string.indexOf(subString, pos);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            ++n;
            pos += step;
        } else break;
    }
    return n;
}
```

### Usage

```
occurrences("foofoofoo", "bar"); //0

occurrences("foofoofoo", "foo"); //3

occurrences("foofoofoo", "foofoo"); //1
```

#### allowOverlapping

```
occurrences("foofoofoo", "foofoo", true); //2
```

Matches:

```
  foofoofoo
1 `----´
2    `----´
```

### Unit Test

- https://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/5axuh96u/

### Benchmark

> I've made a benchmark test and my function is more then 10 times
> faster then the regexp match function posted by gumbo. In my test
> string is 25 chars length. with 2 occurences of the character 'o'. I
> executed 1 000 000 times in Safari.
>
> **Safari 5.1**
>
> Benchmark> Total time execution: 5617 ms (regexp)
>
> Benchmark> Total time execution: 881 ms  (my function 6.4x faster)
>
> **Firefox 4**
>
> Benchmark> Total time execution: 8547 ms (Rexexp)
>
> Benchmark> Total time execution:  634 ms  (my function 13.5x faster)
>
> ---
>
> Edit: changes I've made
>
> - cached substring length
> - added type-casting to string.
> - added optional 'allowOverlapping' parameter
> - fixed correct output for "" empty substring case.

##### Gist

- https://gist.github.com/victornpb/7736865

Comment: I've tried different answers in this topic, and this answer turned out to behaving around 5-10% better performance in large amounts ( compared to other answers).

Answer (score 219):

```js
function countInstances(string, word) {
   return string.split(word).length - 1;
}
console.log(countInstances("This is a string", "is"))
```

Comment: for me is working without the -1

Comment: Benchmarked it with https://jsbench.me/ against the solution "occurrences" from Vitim.us, almost same performance. A simple "split" is my preferred solution as it is the easiest one. The regexes are a bit slower.

Comment: @Ast without -1 the count would be wrong

Answer (score 115):

You can try this:

```js
var theString = "This is a string.";
console.log(theString.split("is").length - 1);
```

Answer (score 43):

My solution:

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";

function countOccurrences(str, value) {
  var regExp = new RegExp(value, "gi");
  return (str.match(regExp) || []).length;
}

console.log(countOccurrences(temp, 'is'));
```

Comment: maybe it would be better to return (str.match(regExp) || []).length; That way you don't evaluate the regular expression twice?

Comment: you also need to scape your string or `countOcurrences('Hello...','.')==8` and not 3

Answer (score 19):

You can use `match` to define such function:

```
String.prototype.count = function(search) {
    var m = this.match(new RegExp(search.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "g"));
    return m ? m.length:0;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted it to be uniform with JS's search semantics, the return line would be `return m ? m.length:-1;`.

Answer (score 14):

Just code-golfing [Rebecca Chernoff](/users/181481/rebecca-chernoff)'s [solution](/a/4009768) :-)

```
alert(("This is a string.".match(/is/g) || []).length);
```

Answer (score 14):

**The non-regex version:**

```js
 var string = 'This is a string',
    searchFor = 'is',
    count = 0,
    pos = string.indexOf(searchFor);

while (pos > -1) {
    ++count;
    pos = string.indexOf(searchFor, ++pos);
}

console.log(count);   // 2
```

Comment: 1. It's only for single char search, too subtle 2. even OP asks for `is` occurences

Comment: This is probably the fastest implementation here, but it would be even faster if you replaced "++pos" with "pos+=searchFor.length"

Answer (score 12):

```js
String.prototype.Count = function (find) {
    return this.split(find).length - 1;
}

console.log("This is a string.".Count("is"));
```

This will return 2.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the fastest function!

Why is it faster?

- Doesn't check char by char (with 1 exception)
- Uses a while and increments 1 var (the char count var) vs. a for loop checking the length and incrementing 2 vars (usually var i and a var with the char count)
- Uses WAY less vars
- Doesn't use regex!
- Uses an (hopefully) highly optimized function
- All operations are as combined as they can be, avoiding slowdowns due to multiple operations

  ```
  String.prototype.timesCharExist=function(c){var t=0,l=0,c=(c+'')[0];while(l=this.indexOf(c,l)+1)++t;return t};
  ```

Here is a slower and more readable version:

```
    String.prototype.timesCharExist = function ( chr ) {
        var total = 0, last_location = 0, single_char = ( chr + '' )[0];
        while( last_location = this.indexOf( single_char, last_location ) + 1 )
        {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        return total;
    };
```

This one is slower because of the counter, long var names and misuse of 1 var.

To use it, you simply do this:

```
    'The char "a" only shows up twice'.timesCharExist('a');
```

**Edit: (2013/12/16)**

DON'T use with Opera 12.16 or older! it will take almost 2.5x more than the regex solution!

On chrome, this solution will take between 14ms and 20ms for 1,000,000 characters.

The regex solution takes 11-14ms for the same amount.

Using a function (outside `String.prototype`) will take about 10-13ms.

Here is the code used:

```
    String.prototype.timesCharExist=function(c){var t=0,l=0,c=(c+'')[0];while(l=this.indexOf(c,l)+1)++t;return t};

    var x=Array(100001).join('1234567890');

    console.time('proto');x.timesCharExist('1');console.timeEnd('proto');

    console.time('regex');x.match(/1/g).length;console.timeEnd('regex');

    var timesCharExist=function(x,c){var t=0,l=0,c=(c+'')[0];while(l=x.indexOf(c,l)+1)++t;return t;};

    console.time('func');timesCharExist(x,'1');console.timeEnd('func');
```

The result of all the solutions should be 100,000!

Note: if you want this function to count more than 1 char, change where is `c=(c+'')[0]` into `c=c+''`

Comment: the prototype was AN EXAMPLE! You can use the function as you please! You can even do this: var timesFunctionExist=function(x,c){var t=0,l=0,c=(c+'')[0];while(l=x.indexOf(c,l)+1)++t;return t}); alert(timesCharExist('The char "a" only shows up twice','a'));! (this will speed up a little more cause i wont be messing with prototypes). If you think I'm wrong, why don't you show it before throwing rocks at me? Prove to me that my function sucks and i will accept it. Show me a test case. And the length of vars does have influence on speed. You can test it.

Answer (score 7):

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";
console.log((temp.match(new RegExp("is", "g")) || []).length);
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way would be to split the string on the required word, the word for which we want to calculate the number of occurences, and subtract 1 from the number of parts:

```
function checkOccurences(string, word) {
      return string.split(word).length - 1;
}
const text="Let us see. see above, see below, see forward, see backward, see left, see right until we will be right"; 
const count=countOccurences(text,"see "); // 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the purpose for regex is much different from `indexOf`.
`indexOf` simply find the occurance of a certain string while in regex you can use wildcards like `[A-Z]` which means it will find **any** capital character in the word without stating the actual character.

Example:

```js
 var index = "This is a string".indexOf("is");
 console.log(index);
 var length = "This is a string".match(/[a-z]/g).length;
 // where [a-z] is a regex wildcard expression thats why its slower
 console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Super duper old, but I needed to do something like this today and only thought to check SO afterwards. Works pretty fast for me.

```
String.prototype.count = function(substr,start,overlap) {
    overlap = overlap || false;
    start = start || 0;

    var count = 0, 
        offset = overlap ? 1 : substr.length;

    while((start = this.indexOf(substr, start) + offset) !== (offset - 1))
        ++count;
    return count;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
       var myString = "This is a string.";
        var foundAtPosition = 0;
        var Count = 0;
        while (foundAtPosition != -1)
        {
            foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("is",foundAtPosition);
            if (foundAtPosition != -1)
            {
                Count++;
                foundAtPosition++;
            }
        }
        document.write("There are " + Count + " occurrences of the word IS");
```

Refer :- [count a substring appears in the string](http://bit.ly/1yT1nAf) for step by step explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that finds this thread in the future, note that the accepted answer will not always return the correct value if you generalize it, since it will choke on regex operators like `$` and `.`. Here's a better version, that can handle *any* needle:

```
function occurrences (haystack, needle) {
  var _needle = needle
    .replace(/\[/g, '\\[')
    .replace(/\]/g, '\\]')
  return (
    haystack.match(new RegExp('[' + _needle + ']', 'g')) || []
  ).length
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Building upon @Vittim.us answer above. I like the control his method gives me, making it easy to extend, but I needed to add case insensitivity and limit matches to whole words with support for punctuation. (e.g. "bath" is in "take a bath." but not "bathing")

The punctuation regex came from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25575009/497745 ([How can I strip all punctuation from a string in JavaScript using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex))

```
function keywordOccurrences(string, subString, allowOverlapping, caseInsensitive, wholeWord)
{

    string += "";
    subString += "";
    if (subString.length <= 0) return (string.length + 1); //deal with empty strings

    if(caseInsensitive)
    {            
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        subString = subString.toLowerCase();
    }

    var n = 0,
        pos = 0,
        step = allowOverlapping ? 1 : subString.length,
        stringLength = string.length,
        subStringLength = subString.length;

    while (true)
    {
        pos = string.indexOf(subString, pos);
        if (pos >= 0)
        {
            var matchPos = pos;
            pos += step; //slide forward the position pointer no matter what

            if(wholeWord) //only whole word matches are desired
            {
                if(matchPos > 0) //if the string is not at the very beginning we need to check if the previous character is whitespace
                {                        
                    if(!/[\s\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&\(\)*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/.test(string[matchPos - 1])) //ignore punctuation
                    {
                        continue; //then this is not a match
                    }
                }

                var matchEnd = matchPos + subStringLength;
                if(matchEnd < stringLength - 1)
                {                        
                    if (!/[\s\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&\(\)*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/.test(string[matchEnd])) //ignore punctuation
                    {
                        continue; //then this is not a match
                    }
                }
            }

            ++n;                
        } else break;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Please feel free to modify and refactor this answer if you spot bugs or improvements.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the js `split` function, and it's length minus 1 will be the number of occurrences.

```
var temp = "This is a string.";
alert(temp.split('is').length-1);
```

Comment: Welcome. SO works differently than forums. SO is designed such that good answers should be upvoted, not duplicated. The answer you have suggested already exists, so you should upvote it instead. There are also answers using the same concept at its base, but also consider a more nuanced interpretation (eg, should `ss` in `sss` count as `1` or `2`? ). So maybe upvote those as well, if you like. For onboarding, please read up on "how to answer" & "how to ask" topics in the help section, linked to at the top of every page. We appreciate & look forward to your future contributions.

Comment: That said, great on posting in a concise, clear manner, with an attempt to provide an explanation, which many of the oldest answers failed to do. To be clear, their code-only answers are discouraged on SO (though it wasn't always well enforced back then). Looking forward to seeing more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
<?php 
$str = "33,33,56,89,56,56";
echo substr_count($str, '56');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var temp = "33,33,56,89,56,56";
var count = temp.match(/56/g);  
alert(count.length);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple version without regex:

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";

var count = (temp.split('is').length - 1);

alert(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

No one will ever see this, but it's good to bring back recursion and arrow functions once in a while (pun gloriously intended)

```
String.prototype.occurrencesOf = function(s, i) {
 return (n => (n === -1) ? 0 : 1 + this.occurrencesOf(s, n + 1))(this.indexOf(s, (i || 0)));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function substrCount( str, x ) {
   let count = -1, pos = 0;
   do {
     pos = str.indexOf( x, pos ) + 1;
     count++;
   } while( pos > 0 );
   return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

ES2020 offers a new MatchAll which might be of use in this particular context.

Here we create a new RegExp, please ensure you pass 'g' into the function.

Convert the result using Array.from and count the length, which returns 2 as per the original requestor's desired output.

```js
let strToCheck = RegExp('is', 'g')
let matchesReg = "This is a string.".matchAll(strToCheck)
console.log(Array.from(matchesReg).length) // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

added this optimization:

[How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string#22421387)

> This is probably the fastest implementation here, but it would be even faster if you replaced "++pos" with "pos+=searchFor.length" –
> hanshenrik

```js
function occurrences(str_, subStr) {
  let occurence_count = 0
  let pos = -subStr.length
  while ((pos = str_.indexOf(subStr, pos + subStr.length)) > -1) {
    occurence_count++
  }
  return occurence_count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this is a very old thread i've come across but as many have pushed their answer's, here is mine in a hope to help someone with this simple code.

```js
var search_value = "This is a dummy sentence!";
var letter = 'a'; /*Can take any letter, have put in a var if anyone wants to use this variable dynamically*/
letter = letter && "string" === typeof letter ? letter : "";
var count;
for (var i = count = 0; i < search_value.length; count += (search_value[i++] == letter));
console.log(count);
```

I'm not sure if it is the fastest solution but i preferred it for simplicity and for not using regex (i just don't like using them!)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
let count = s.length - s.replace(/is/g, "").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, in 2022, using map() and filter() :

```
string = "Xanthous: A person with yellow hair. Her hair was very xanthous in colour."       
count = string.split('').map((e,i) => { if(e === 'e') return i;}).filter(Boolean).length
```

Just for the fun of using these functions. The example counts the number of "e" in my string.

This is the same as using the match() function :

```
(string.match(/e/g)||[]).length
```

or simply the split() function:

```
string.split('e').length - 1
```

I think the best is to use match(), because it consumes less resources! My answer is just for fun and to show that there are many possibilities to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I hope it would help someone

```
const countOccurence = (string, char) => {
const chars = string.match(new RegExp(char, 'g')).length
return chars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countInstances = function(body, target) {
  var globalcounter = 0;
  var concatstring  = '';
  for(var i=0,j=target.length;i<body.length;i++){
    concatstring = body.substring(i-1,j);
    
    if(concatstring === target){
       globalcounter += 1;
       concatstring = '';
    }
  }
  
  
  return globalcounter;
 
};

console.log(   countInstances('abcabc', 'abc')   ); // ==> 2
console.log(   countInstances('ababa', 'aba')   ); // ==> 2
console.log(   countInstances('aaabbb', 'ab')   ); // ==> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

---

**`substr_count` translated to Javascript from php**

---

- [Locutus (Package that translates Php to JS)](https://locutus.io/php)
- [substr_count (official page, code copied below)](https://locutus.io/php/strings/substr_count)

```
function substr_count (haystack, needle, offset, length) { 
  // eslint-disable-line camelcase
  //  discuss at: https://locutus.io/php/substr_count/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (https://kvz.io)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman (https://twitter.com/onnomarsman)
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (https://brett-zamir.me)
  // improved by: Thomas
  //   example 1: substr_count('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'e')
  //   returns 1: 3
  //   example 2: substr_count('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'K', 1)
  //   returns 2: 0
  //   example 3: substr_count('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'Z', 0, 10)
  //   returns 3: false

  var cnt = 0

  haystack += ''
  needle += ''
  if (isNaN(offset)) {
    offset = 0
  }
  if (isNaN(length)) {
    length = 0
  }
  if (needle.length === 0) {
    return false
  }
  offset--

  while ((offset = haystack.indexOf(needle, offset + 1)) !== -1) {
    if (length > 0 && (offset + needle.length) > length) {
      return false
    }
    cnt++
  }

  return cnt
}
```

**Check out Locutus's Translation Of Php's substr_count function**

Answer (score 0):

The parameters:
ustring: the superset string
countChar: the substring

A function to count substring occurrence in JavaScript:

```js
function subStringCount(ustring, countChar){
  var correspCount = 0;
  var corresp = false;
  var amount = 0;
  var prevChar = null;
  
 for(var i=0; i!=ustring.length; i++){

     if(ustring.charAt(i) == countChar.charAt(0) && corresp == false){
       corresp = true;
       correspCount += 1;
       if(correspCount == countChar.length){
         amount+=1;
         corresp = false;
         correspCount = 0;
       }
       prevChar = 1;
     }
     else if(ustring.charAt(i) == countChar.charAt(prevChar) && corresp == true){
       correspCount += 1;
       if(correspCount == countChar.length){
         amount+=1;
         corresp = false;
         correspCount = 0;
         prevChar = null;
       }else{
         prevChar += 1 ;
       }
     }else{
       corresp = false;
       correspCount = 0;
     }
 } 
 return amount;
}

console.log(subStringCount('Hello World, Hello World', 'll'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'stackoverflow';
var arr = Array.from(str);
console.log(arr);

for (let a = 0; a <= arr.length; a++) {
  var temp = arr[a];
  var c = 0;
  for (let b = 0; b <= arr.length; b++) {
    if (temp === arr[b]) {
      c++;
    }

  }
  console.log(`the ${arr[a]} is counted for ${c}`)
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Iterate less the second time (just when first letter of substring matches) but still uses 2 for loops:

```
   function findSubstringOccurrences(str, word) {
        let occurrences = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            if(word[0] === str[i]){ // to make it faster and iterate less
                for(let j=0; j<word.length; j++){
                    if(str[i+j] !== word[j]) break;
                    if(j === word.length - 1) occurrences++;
                }
            }
        }
        return occurrences;
    }
    
    console.log(findSubstringOccurrences("jdlfkfomgkdjfomglo", "omg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this code

const countSubStr = (str, search) => {
    let arrStr = str.split('');
    let i = 0, count = 0;

    while(i < arrStr.length){
        let subStr = i + search.length + 1 <= arrStr.length ?
                  arrStr.slice(i, i+search.length).join('') :
                  arrStr.slice(i).join('');
        if(subStr === search){
            count++;
            arrStr.splice(i, search.length);
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = 'This is the lorel ipsum text';
var mycharArray = mystring.split('');
var opArr = [];
for(let i=0;i<mycharArray.length;i++){
if(mycharArray[i]=='i'){//match the character you want to match
    opArr.push(i);
  }}
console.log(opArr); // it will return matching index position
console.log(opArr.length); // it will return length
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getLetterMatchCount = (guessedWord, secretWord) => {
  const secretLetters = secretWord.split('');
  const guessedLetterSet = new Set(guessedWord);
  return secretLetters.filter(letter => guessedLetterSet.has(letter)).length;
};
const str = "rahul";
const str1 = "rajendra";

getLetterMatchCount(str, str1)
```

Comment: With so many other answers, it would be good if you added some explanation as to how your code works and what advantages it has over other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This function works in three modes: looking for the frequency of a single character within a string , a contiguous substring within a string then if it does match one it moves right ahead to next one right after it , and the third is similar to the previous one except it it will also count intersecting substrings within the given string

```js
function substringFrequency(string , substring , conjunction){
    let index 
    let occurenceFrequency  = 0
    for (let i=0 ; i < string.length  ; i++){
        index = string.indexOf(substring , i)
        if (index != -1){
            if ((substring.length == 1 ) || conjunction == true) {
                i = index 
            }else {
                i = index + 1
            }
            occurenceFrequency++
        }else{
            break
        } 
    }
    return (occurenceFrequency)
}

console.log(substringFrequency('vvvv' , 'v' ))
console.log(substringFrequency('vvvv' , 'vv'))
console.log(substringFrequency('vvvv' , 'vv' , true))
```

Comment: @Calculuswhiz got it more integrated with the for loop code block

Comment: @Calculuswhiz initially my first edit was due to your comment to solely integrate the variable i within the for loop body , still during so i've noticed that intersecting substrings gets omitted , and that only separate substrings are counted . so i defaulted to count separate ones as it made more sense , yet as the original question didn't explicitly specify any and i don't want to impose any behavior in order to accommodate varying use cases ,i appended more statements .

Answer (score 0):

This function will tell you if the substring is in the string and how many times.

```js
const wordInText = (wordToFind, wholeText) => {
    const wordToFindRegex = new RegExp(wordToFind, 'gi');
    const occurences = wholeText.match(wordToFindRegex) ?? [];
    return {isWordInText: occurences.length > 0, occurences: occurences.length};
 }
 
 console.log(wordInText("is", "This cow jumped over this moon"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer for Leandro Batista :
just a problem with the regex expression.

```js
 "use strict";
 var dataFromDB = "testal";
 
  $('input[name="tbInput"]').on("change",function(){
 var charToTest = $(this).val();
 var howManyChars = charToTest.length;
 var nrMatches = 0;
 if(howManyChars !== 0){
  charToTest = charToTest.charAt(0);
  var regexp = new RegExp(charToTest,'gi');
  var arrMatches = dataFromDB.match(regexp);
  nrMatches = arrMatches ? arrMatches.length : 0;
 }
  $('#result').html(nrMatches.toString());

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
What do you wanna count <input type="text" name="tbInput" value=""><br />
Number of occurences = <span id="result">0</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

***[came across this post.](https://javascript.info/string)***

```
let str = 'As sly as a fox, as strong as an ox';

let target = 'as'; // let's look for it

let pos = 0;
while (true) {
  let foundPos = str.indexOf(target, pos);
  if (foundPos == -1) break;

  alert( `Found at ${foundPos}` );
  pos = foundPos + 1; // continue the search from the next position
}
```

***The same algorithm can be layed out shorter:***

```
let str = "As sly as a fox, as strong as an ox";
let target = "as";

let pos = -1;
while ((pos = str.indexOf(target, pos + 1)) != -1) {
  alert( pos );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
function countString(str, search){
    var count=0;
    var index=str.indexOf(search);
    while(index!=-1){
        count++;
        index=str.indexOf(search,index+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```