# Algo for finding a number of occurrences of every string from a set within a one larger string

Tags: search, substring

I have a large string A and a set of relatively small strings B*.

How can I efficiently find the number of occurrences of each string from B* inside A?

I suspect that suffix tree can be used here but I don't know how exactly to do that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Comment: @SamarRizvi: this is clearly not what I'm looking for. I can loop through my set of strings and run the search for each of them but that would be extremely slow.