# how to count number of values for each row in *.CSV file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, row

My csv Data looking like this

```
1,2,"hi,how ar you?",abc
3,5,a,b,c
expected output should be
4
5
```

Comment: Here is what you should find for :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952805/count-number-of-lines-in-csv-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
'1,2,"hi,how ar you?",abc'.match(/"[^"]*"|[^,]+/g).length
4
'3,5,a,b,c'.match(/"[^"]*"|[^,]+/g).length
5
```

Comment: Wonder the OP cares about escaped quotes within quoted values?

Comment: Well, if he asked, there should be way to do it too.

Comment: hi,thanks can you tell me how to read line by line from csv file ?

Comment: read the whole file and split it with "\n" or "\r\n" like `csv_file_content.split("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method which is derived from another post here:

```
   var csvLines = '1,2,"how ar you?",abc' + "\n" + '1,4,"fine",6,7';
   var splitByChars = ',';

   var totalCount = 0;
   var linesArray = csvLines.split("\n");

   var lineCount = 0;

   while (lineCount < linesArray.length) {
       totalCount += StringCount(csvLines, splitByChars);
       lineCount++;
   }

   alert(totalCount);

   function StringCount(stringToSplit, splitBy) {
       var words = stringToSplit.split(splitBy);
       return words.length;
   }
```

Comment: Here the link where the source code came from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893634/string-split-and-count-the-number-of-occurrences-and-also

Comment: I think he just wants to know the number of columns in each row, not the count of occurrences of each word. And it doesn't look like you do anything to keep from treating `"hi,how ar you?"` as 2 columns.

Comment: i am expecting the same answer as Barmer