# In Javascript or Underscore, can I count how many instances of a substring within an array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This must be so simple, yet I can't quite figure out how to count the number of substrings within an array of things. Anything in Underscore for this that I'm missing?

```
var foo = ["fred", "ted", "medical", "car"]

function howManySubstringsInArray(arr, word){
    var i = arr.length,
    j = 0;
    while (i) if (arr[--i].indexOf(word))++j;
    return j;
}

howManySubstringsInArray(foo, 'ed')
Output => 3
```

This isn't working.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Comment: Should it match multiple substrings in one word?

Comment: you should use `arr[--i].indexOf(word) != -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you don't care about repeated matches *within* each array element, you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to find matching elements:

NB: this is a standard ECMAScript 5 function, not from underscore.  There's a shim for older browsers at the above link.

```
function howManySubstringsInArray(arr, word) {
    return arr.filter(function(v) {
        return v.indexOf(word) >= 0;
    }).length;
}
```

Strictly speaking this is creating a new array which is *slightly* wasteful since all we're doing is counting the elements, but for "small" lists it won't matter.

A bare loop would actually work pretty well anyhow - you just need to make sure the loop is structured correctly, and that you actually look at the result of the `.indexOf` call.  Your existing backwards iteration makes the loop conditions far harder to follow than they need to be:

```
function howManySubstringsInArray(arr, word) {
    var i = 0, n = arr.length, count = 0;
    for ( ; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(word) >= 0) {
             ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: That'll miss repeats in the same string, such as "bedded".

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking for help with the code, knowing it's wrong.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's code is wrong because he didn't check the result of `indexOf` - he never attempts to iterate over each string.

Comment: It may be useful if the OP indicates whether repeats in the string are significant.

Comment: Looks like the OP doesn't care about repeats in the same string (see comment on loganfsmyth's answer).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that's what I surmised (and I did consider that before answering, BTW).

Comment: Thanks guys- repeats within the strings are not significant. Only need to check once per array element.

Comment: This sure looks sexier than a "clumsy" loop, but I don't like it. It's wasteful just for the sake of looking good.

Comment: @Jon fair point, and acknowledged in the update I added at the same time as your comment.  Using `reduce` would be less wasteful, albeit still not as efficient as a bare loop.  It would also be harder to understand for a novice.

Comment: @Alnitak: Spot on. I was happy to see both updates. You have my +1.

Comment: Many thanks gentlemen. I owe you both a beer or beverage of your choice. Let me know next time you are in North Carolina.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop needs to check the actual index.

```
 while (i) if (arr[--i].indexOf(word) !== -1) ++j;
```

You could also use `reduce` well here:

```
function howManySubstringsInArray(arr, word){
  return _.reduce(arr, function(count, val){
    return count + (val.indexOf(word) === -1 ? 0 : 1)
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: That'll miss repeats in the same string, such as "bedded".

Comment: Good point gentlemen. I don't envision checking for repeats within the same element, just once per element is fine.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master: Ah, well, there you are then.

Comment: don't forget the ES5 built-in `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: @Alnitak He asked about underscore in the title, so he probably already has it. Otherwise he would have to add even more code for the shim. In the general case though, I agree.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Many thanks Logan! I really appreciate your help. I haven't ever used _.reduce before. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

```
function howManySubstringsInArray(arr,str)
{
var count=0;
   $.each(arr,function(i,item)){
   if(item.indexOf(str)!=-1)
    {
      count ++;
    }
  });
 return count;
}
```

Change $.each to for if you want.