# Regex to match only if symbol in string used once

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe it's a simple question but today i'm a bit stucked with it.

I need regex to match only if symbol `%` appeared once in a string..

for example:

```
/regexpForSymbol(%)/.test('50%') => true
/regexpForSymbol(%)/.test('50%%') => false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why a regex? Just loop over the characers in the string and count...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use:

```
^[^%]*%[^%]*$
```

The anchors are there to ensure every character is covered, and you probably already know what `[^%]` does.

Comment: You should use PCRE negation(!) ,  ^[!%}*%[!%]*$. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank That is not a valid syntax.

Comment: i don't know for example. put a full explanation when you answer

Comment: @mangusta I don't know... the expression is pretty simple if someone took the time to read the basics of regular expressions... `^` matches the start of string, `[^...]` is a negated class, `*` is a quantifier, and `$` matches the end of the string. The `%` is literal.

Answer (score 11):

Here you go. Don't expect everyone to make these for you all the time though.

```
^      # Start of string
[^%]*  # Any number of a character not matching `%`, including none.
%      # Matching exactly one `%`
[^%]*  # 
$      # End of string
```

Comment: That downvote was unnecessary. I'll gladly delete it if it's a duplicate. Just because it's a duplicate doesn't make it wrong in any way.

Comment: @Kosmetika I've explained the regex for you. This is pretty basic regex. If you like to use regex you should read up on it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex.

```
function checkIfOne(string, char) {
    return string.split(char).length === 2;
}
```

Usage:

```
var myString = "abcde%fgh",
    check = checkIfOne(myString, '%'); // will be true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and count the resulting array:

```
str.match(/%/g).length == 1
```