# Counting all characters in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to count all characters in a string and return it to an object. I have tried but I’m unable to get the correct answer.

This is my code:

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  a.forEach(function(s){
    var count=0;
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
      if(s==a[j]){
        count+=1;
      }
      obj[a[j]]=count;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

Output:

```
{ b: 0, a: 3, n: 2 }
```

Which obviously is wrong.

Can anyone help me with that? Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a nested loop?

Comment: can you please elaborate and give the right code?

Comment: You really just need nothing but `obj[s] = (obj[s] || 0) + 1;` in the `forEach` callback. Counting characters is usually done with `reduce` instead of `forEach`, though.

Comment: See [*counting frequency of characters in a string using javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619785/counting-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript) for a number of alternative solutions.

Comment: Just place `obj[a[j]]=count;` out of the `for loop`

Answer (score 6):

The minimum necessary change is that `obj[a[j]]=count;` should be `obj[s]=count;`, because you have that line running on every iteration of the inner loop regardless of whether `j` refers to the letter you're currently tallying.

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  a.forEach(function(s){
    var count=0;
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
      if(s==a[j]){
        count+=1;
      }
      obj[s]=count;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

However, you don't need a nested loop. Your outer `.forEach()` can update the count for the current letter directly:

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  a.forEach(function(s){
    obj[s] = (obj[s] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

This can be made shorter with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example):

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  return str.split("").reduce(function(obj, s){
    obj[s] = (obj[s] || 0) + 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

Note that `(obj[s] || 0)` means to use `obj[s]`'s value if it is truthy, otherwise use `0`. So the first time you encounter a particular letter `obj[s]` will be `undefined`, which is falsey, so then `0` will be used. The next time you encounter that letter `obj[s]` will be `1`, which is truthy.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can count by better performance, you loop more than you needed!

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
    if(typeof obj[a[j]] !== 'undefined'){
      obj[a[j]]+=1;
    } else {
      obj[a[j]]=1;
     }
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a *reduce* operation, like so

```js
const str = "banana"
const charCounts = Array.from(str).reduce((counts, char) => {
  counts[char] = (counts[char] || 0) + 1
  return counts
}, Object.create(null))

console.info(charCounts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need not to use a `forEach` and a `for` loop together when you can do it with only `foreach`. Here is the code.

```js
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  a.forEach(function(s) {
    if (obj[s]) {
      obj[s] = obj[s] + 1;
    } else {
      obj[s] = 1;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well, that was really helpful.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you assign the `obj[a[j]] = count;` when the counting is not yet complete. You should do change your `function(s)` to this:

```
  function(s){
    var count=0;
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
      if(s==a[j]){
        count+=1;
      }
    }
    obj[s]=count;
  }
```

Another comment: you code is very inefficient, which is `O(n^2)`. You can simplify it much further to get an `O(n)` algorithm with this:

```
  function(s){
    if (obj[s] == undefined) {
       obj[s] = 1;
    } else {
       obj[s] = obj[s] + 1;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Already so many friends submitted their opinions and cool solutions. Here is my solution with the simplest code:

```js
const src = 'banana';

const count = str => 
  [...str].reduce((acc, val) => (acc[val] ? (acc[val]++) : (acc[val]=1), acc),{});
  
console.log(count(src));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Hope you enjoy my code. Thanks.

Comment: I'll make it even a bit more concise, if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I got it

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't the prettiest, but I'm hoping it shows how you can use console to help debug loops.

```
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("");
  var obj = {};
  a.forEach(function(s){
  console.log(s);
    var count=0;
    for(var j in a){

      // commas can come in really handy and help avoid huge debug blocks.
      console.log('_',j,s,a[j]); 

      if(s==a[j]){
        console.log('count++');
        count++;
      }
      obj[s] = count;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to bring `obj[a[j]]=count` inside your `if` statement.

this should return correct results

```
function countAllCharacters(str) {
  var a = str.split("")
  var obj = {}
  a.forEach(function(s){
    var count=0
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
      if(s===a[j]){
        count+=1
        obj[a[j]]=count
      }
    }
  })
  return obj
}
console.log(countAllCharacters('banana'))
```

the increment in `obj` must also satisfy the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countAllCharacters(str) {
   let newArr = str.split('');  // splits the string into a new array
   let obj = {};  // initiliza an empty object

   newArr.forEach(char => (obj[char]) ? obj[char] += 1 : obj[char] = 1);
   return obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let name = "banana";
 // First we have to remove space from the string
 name = name.replace(/\s/g, "");
 for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
   let count = 0;
   for (let j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
     if (name[i] == name[j] && i > j) {
       break;
     }
     if (name[i] == name[j]) {
       count++
     }
   }
   if (count) {
     console.log(name[i], count);
   }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).