# Javascript: Counting frequency of emojis in text

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to count the frequency of emojis in a block of text. For example:

```
"I love  so much  " -> [{:3}, {:1}]
```

In order to count the frequency of characters in a block of text, I'm using

```
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619975/4975358

^The above code works great, but it does not recognize emoji characters:

```
{�: 1,  �: 3,  �: 2}
```

Also, I'd prefer the output to be a list of json objects of length 1, as opposed to one long json object.

Comment: _"list of json objects of length 1"_ do you mean an object with a single key value? eg `[{�: 1},{�: 3},{�: 2}]` Why? That would require unnecessary looping to look up the count for any specific emoji.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. That's just the input format another function requires

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the callback of the `String.replace` function and a unicode aware `RegExp` detecting everything from the unicode blocks *"Miscellaneous Symbols"* to *"Pictographs Transport and Map Symbols"* (0x1F300 to 0x1F6FF):

```js
let str = "I love  so much  ";

let freq = {};
str.replace(/[\u{1F300}-\u{1F6FF}]/gu, char => freq[char] = (freq[char] || 0) + 1);

console.log(freq);
```

If you prefer to avoid `RegExp` or `String.replace`, you can destructure the string into an array and reduce it to the frequencies as follows:

```js
let str = "I love  so much  ";

let freq = [...str].reduce((freq, char) => {
  if (char >= '\u{1F300}' && char < '\u{1F700}') freq[char] = (freq[char] || 0) + 1;
  return freq;
}, {});

console.log(freq);
```

Answer (score 6):

`charAt` won't help you here. `for...of` will parse the string correctly into Unicode codepoints including those in the astral plane. We use `character.length` to determine whether or not this is a supplementary plane character. If you really want to know if it's an emoji, you'd need to tighten this up.

```js
const input = "I love  so much  ";
    
function getFrequency(string) {
  var freq = {};
  for (character of string) {
    if (character.length === 1) continue;
    if (freq[character]) {
      freq[character]++;
    } else {
      freq[character] = 1;
    }
  }
  return freq;
 };
 
 console.log(getFrequency(input));
```

To create an array of single-valued objects, run the output through this:

```
function breakProperties(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    var result = {};
    result[key] = obj[key];
    return result;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is picking up the emojis perfectly! How could I modify the output so that only the emojis were being counted?

Comment: It won't count the heart emoji. which having character length  = 1