# Java Script Regex for match characters with exact frequency

Tags: javascript

All characters in input string have the same exact frequency (i.e. occur the same number of times), for example, **"xxyyzz"** is valid, but **"xyyzzz"** is not valid.

can anyone provide regex for same.

Comment: What have you tried and what code have you written?

Comment: And would `"xyzxzy"` be valid? I really doubt regex can do that

Comment: Not with regex alone. Maybe split on `.` then iterate over, use the found character as an index and increase its value. At the end check that all indices have the same count.

Comment: yes "xyzxzy" valid but "xzxzy" is not valid.

Comment: No, you'll have to count them.

Comment: Why do you require _especially_ a regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Without** regex, here is something that works:

(count the frequency of each character, and just check that they are all the same)

```js
// Function taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619785/counting-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};

function isValid(string) {
    let freq = getFrequency(string);
    let first = Object.values(freq)[0];
    return Object.values(freq).every(i => i == first);
}

let testStrings = ["xyyzzz", "xxyyzz", "xxyyzzz"];
for (let test of testStrings) {
    console.log(`Is "${test}" valid? ${isValid(test)}`);
}
```

**With regex**, and as comments have noticed, it's unlikely that you will have a good solution that applies for any case.

The count method as above is pretty simple and fairly efficient (even though there is probably some room for improvement)

Answer (score 0):

Just a combination of regex and e.g. a truthy/falsy check over a list of regex matches can do the job.

The most simple approach I could think of looks like that ...

```js
console.log('xxxYYYzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length)));   // passes.
console.log('xxxYYzzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length)));   // fails.
console.log('xxxYYYzzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length)));  // fails.
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... and on top of this proof of concept one could build something similar to the next solution ...

```js
//
//  ... proof of concept test cases ...
//
//  pass: 'xxxYYYzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length))
//  fail: 'xxxYYzzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length))
//  fail: 'xxxYYYzzzz'.match(/(.)\1*/g).every((elm, idx, arr) => (elm.length === arr[0].length))
//

function testCharacterFrequency(str) {
  const matchList = str.match(/(.)\1*/g) || []; // e.g. ["xxx", "YYY", "zzz"] for (str = 'xxxYYYzzz')
  const harmonyTestLength = (matchList.length >= 2) && matchList[0].length;

  const isHarmonic = !!harmonyTestLength && matchList.every(elm => (elm.length === harmonyTestLength));
  const frequencyLength = (isHarmonic && harmonyTestLength) || -1;

  return {
    isHarmonic,
    frequencyLength
  }
}

console.log("testCharacterFrequency('xxxYYYzzz') : ", testCharacterFrequency('xxxYYYzzz'));
console.log("testCharacterFrequency('xxxYYYzzz') : ", testCharacterFrequency('xxxYYzzzz'));

console.log("testCharacterFrequency('aaaaaBBBBBcccccDDDDDeeeee') : ", testCharacterFrequency('aaaaaBBBBBcccccDDDDDeeeee'));
console.log("testCharacterFrequency('aaaaaBBBBBcccccDDDDDeeeeE') : ", testCharacterFrequency('aaaaaBBBBBcccccDDDDDeeeeE'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```