# Can anyone help me to get the string replacing with '(' of a given string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone help me to get the string characters replacing with '(' for single repetition of a character  and replacing with ')' for multiple repetition of a character from a given string in JavaScript.

For Example:

```js
let a = "abbcdeeff";
// Output -> ())(())))
```

Comment: Show us your approach please

Comment: Hi, A random string of character is passed, for example: "draft" I need the output to be as (((((. If I pass the string value as "people" I need the output to be as ))()()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let a = "abbcdeeff";
// Output -> ())(())))
function getResult(text){
  const stringToTest = text.split('');
  let OutputString ='';
  for (var i=0; i< stringToTest.length; i++) {
        let count = 0;
        for (var j=0; j<stringToTest.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
                count++;
        }
        count == 1 ? OutputString += '(' : OutputString += ')';       
    }
    return OutputString;
}
console.log(getResult(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this using frequency counting from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58600923/295783)

```js
const counter = s => [...s].reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = a[c] + 1 || 1) && a, {})

const tranformStr = s => {
  const freq = counter(s)
  return s.replace(/./g,char => freq[char] > 1 ? ")" : "(")
};


let a = "abbcdeeff"; // Output -> ())(())))
console.log(tranformStr(a))
let b = "draft";
console.log(tranformStr(b)); // (((((
let c = "people"
console.log(tranformStr(c)); // ))()()
```

Comment: Hi, What if we pass any random string. How to replace those characters in the string.

Comment: @Ram Please see updated and corrected answer