# Word count in flash?

Tags: flash, count, adobe, cpu-word, jsfl

Does anyone know if I could get a word count from an fla? Maybe this could be done with a JSFL? (I'm not sure). I have 7 large FLA files with 100s of MCs containing text. I now need to get a word count but not sure if it's possible without going into every clip and copying/pasting into word!! (I'm hoping not). I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: texts are placed in static or dynamic text fields?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about **TLF** text fields in [JSFL documention](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_extending_reference.pdf). This works with **classic** text fields:

```
var str="find me";
var doc=fl.getDocumentDOM();
var txt = fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", doc); // find classic text fields
for each (var t in txt) {
    count+=occurrences(t.obj.getTextString(),str);
}
/*var tlf = fl.findObjectInDocByType("tlfText", doc);
for each (var t in results) {
    fl.trace(t.obj.getTextString()); //dosen't work
}*/
fl.trace(count);

function occurrences(string, subString, allowOverlapping){
    string+=""; subString+="";
    if(subString.length<=0) return string.length+1;
    var n=0, pos=0;
    var step=(allowOverlapping)?(1):(subString.length);
    while(true){
        pos=string.indexOf(subString,pos);
        if(pos>=0){ n++; pos+=step; } else break;
    }
    return(n);
}
```

[JS - How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924240/1696720)