# How to detect new empty line in textarea with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to detect a new empty line in a text area and if the user just pressed enter in the text area, without entering any data to return false and echo a message. I have made some research and thought of something like this:

```
var validatef ....
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if (validatef == 'a value here' || code == 13) { 
  somevarhere.textcontent = 'Message';
  return false;
}
else {....}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @bksi I mean that when the user hits enter without entering any data, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: New empty line and pressed enter? What about just detect two consecutive pressed enters?

Comment: @Arantir How to do that?

Comment: @Adrian, Add +1 to some counter variable on enter pressed and -1 on any other key. On any key pressed check if counter > 2 and do your stuff.

Comment: What event listener contains the above code?

Comment: @Akshay onsubmit="return validatef()"

Comment: I'm not sure if we get keyCode onSubmit. I think you are looking for onkeydown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var val = $('textarea').val();
    if (e.which == 13) {
if(! /\S/.test(val)) {
   alert("no data");
}
    }
});
```

this alerts no data for each keypress.

This is in jQuery but it will be similar even in plain Javascript

> Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/TUCx8/

Comment: Would have been great if it was javascript don;t know how $('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) translates to javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can detect an empty line in a textarea by checking for the values:

`\r\n` (works fine for me) or `\n`

Just replace the text `a value here` with `\r\n` or `\n` what best suits you.

**EDIT:**

Check [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string) to count regex appearances. So you can make a `for` loop to show the error message on `/\s/g`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: \r\n? Isn't it just \n now?

Comment: Well, \r\n works like a charm for me in the latest browsers :)

Comment: Dude is right, it works only with \n. But the problem is that i want it to show the error foreach space or for 100 spaces. It works for the first enter, after doesn't

Comment: Well, do a global regex test then. Something like `/\n/g.test(value)`

Comment: Test page: http://jsfiddle.net/gUBCL/ It only works in chrome. Tested in Nightly webkit, FF, chrome, and opera.

Comment: @Adrian: Sorry, the link is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Answer (score 1):

just test if the user pressed enter twice

```
/\n\n/.test(this.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the first sentence of the question, this may be one of  possible solutions:

```
var enters = 0;
$('textarea').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13)
        enters++;
    else
        enters = 0;
    if (enters > 1) {
        alert('You hit 2 new lines!');
    }
});
```

Live example http://jsfiddle.net/fp6xk/

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution is to check an empty line right before the end of text:

```
(function(){
    $('textarea').keyup(function(event) {
        if (/(\r?\n){2}$/.test($(this).val())) {
            alert('2 consecutive empty lines at the end!');
        }
    });
})();
```

It would work independent of consecutive enter presses.
http://jsfiddle.net/fp6xk/4/