# how to find the number of occurences of a substring in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in javascript.

```
    var contents = '<p>this is some text.<span class="Am"></span>This is som text<span class="Am"></span>This is some text<span class="Am"></span></p>';
```

Now I have to find the number of occurences of span tag inside this string and then use a loop throgh this number. For example

```
 function doStuff(){
        var contents = '<p>this is some text.<span class="Am"></span>This is som text<span class="Am"></span>This is some text<span class="Am"></span></p>';
        var spans = 'Number of spans in the string';  // this is required to me
        for(i=1;i<=spans;i++){
            // do some stuff
            }
       }
```

Can anyone tell me how it can be done with javascript ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: THis will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, its pretty hardcode but works:

```
contents.split("</span>").length - 1
```

you can also try this:

```
contents.match(/<span/ig).length
```

Comment: @user2826169 also if you need to take care for `span` and `SPAN` aswell the *insensitive global* `ig` flag might help.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
var temp = document.createElement("DIV");
temp.innerHTML = contents;

var count = temp.getElementsByTagName("SPAN").length;
```

Comment: +1 for letting the browser decide. A quite better (and more flexible) way to accomplish the desired.

Comment: And what if it is not meant for a browser?

Answer (score 1):

dam, folks are quick at answering : ) ...

Here is a reusable way to throw in the mix

```
    /* function stringmatchCount(str,instr) {
       var count = instr.match(/str/g);
       return count.length;
     } */
```

*UPDATE AS ROKO better shows

```
  function stringmatchCount(str,dlm) {
       var d = new RegExp(dlm, "g");
        return str.match(d).length;
     }
```

usage, like in your example.

```
 function doStuff(){
   var contents = '<p><span class="Am"></span>doo, daaa<span></span>';
   var spans = stringmatchCount(contents,'<span');
    for (var i = 0, len=spans; i < len; ++i) {
     ... 
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
contents.match(/\<span\>//g).length
```