# Editing prototype of String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, prototype

This is my code:

```
String.prototype.count = function(character) {
    var seq = new RegExp('/'+character+'/g');
    var matches = this.toString().match(seq);
    return matches
};

'hello world'.count('o');
```

#### This is what it should do:

- Return array of `o`s

#### This is what it's doing:

- Return null

Comment: That's not how you create regex with the RegExp constructor, check the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count string occurrence in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: Also, your method is named very poorly. I would expect a method named `count` to return a single integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.prototype.count = function(character) {
    var seq = new RegExp(character, 'g');
    var matches = this.toString().match(seq);
    return matches;
};

alert('hello world'.count('o'));
```

ps: if you do not want to use regexps in `character` - you should escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the RegExp that you want. It should be:

```
    var seq = new RegExp(character, 'g');
```

When you use the `RegExp` constructor, you just give it the contents of the regular expression, you don't need the `/` delimiters -- those are only used in RegExp literals. Your RegExp is looking for the literal string `/o/g`.