# JS: Regex and global match() not creating an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying ti use match() in order to parse through some text and return the amount of times the text shows up. I'm doing this by using a global match and then calling length on the array that is created from the match. Instead, I'm just getting a array with a single element.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    checkword = "/" + specialWord + "/g";
    finalAnswer = userText.match(specialWord);
    console.log(finalAnswer);
    $('#answer').html(finalAnswer + '<br>' + finalAnswer.length);
    return finalAnswer;
});
```

For example my search for 'is' in "this is" should return an array with a length of two, correct?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Related: [How to count string occurrence in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: If `specialWord` can contain special character, then you might want to escape it before passing it to RegExp constructor like in hwnd's answer

Comment: Or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009787/1338292) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7924240/1338292) in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegExp constructor to do this and you need to change `.match(specialWord)` to `checkword` instead.

```
checkword = new RegExp(specialWord, "g");
finalAnswer = userText.match(checkword);
```