# Replace and get word occurrence count

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, I want to replace the specific word and also want to count the number of occurrence. e.g

```
"Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available.
Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative."
.replace(/source/g,'<b>source</b>');
```

This will replace all `source` with `<b>source</b>` but I want the count of occurance of `source` also i.e `2`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009768

Comment: but that is just giving count not replacing the given word

Comment: Yes, but you already have the first step

Comment: is it possible to it in one go ?

Comment: It is not possible to return 2 values with `replace`. Still you can use a counter and increment it inside a callback function. Are you looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/028etoLg/?

Answer (score 1):

Before the replace call you can simply do:

```js
var count = ("Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available.    Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative.".match(/source/g) || []).length;
var replaceString = "Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available.Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative."
.replace(/source/g,'<b>source</b>');
alert(count);
alert(replaceString);
```

Comment: isn't it two step process ?

Comment: i want both new replaced string and count both

Comment: @Manish:- Updated the code. You have done your 1st step already. To count the occurence of the matched string you can do like above.

Comment: is it possible to it one go ?

Comment: @Manish:- I dont think it is!

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceAndCount(str, tofind, rep){

   var _x = str.split(tofind);
   return{
     "count":_x.length-1,
     "str":_x.join(rep)
   };

}
```

Something like this function.

Now the count will be

```
var str = "Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available.
Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative.";
var count = replaceAndCount(str, "source", "<b>source</b>").count;
```

and new string will be

```
var newString = replaceAndCount(str, "source", "<b>source</b>").str.
```

Comment: is it possible to it one go ?

Comment: What do you mean in one go?

Answer (score 0):

why not split and join?

```
function replaceAndCount( str, toBeReplaced, toBeReplacedBy )
{
  var arr = str.split( "toBeReplaced" );

  return [ arr.join( toBeReplacedBy  ), arr.length ];
}  

replaceAndCount( "Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available. Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative." , "source", "<b>source</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first count the occurencies like this

```
var occurencies = (string.match(/source/g) || []).length;
```

and then replace them

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to return 2 values (both the replaced string *and* the replacement count) with `replace`.

However, you can use a *counter* and *increment it inside a **callback function***.

```js
var count = 0; // Declare the counter
var res = "Of course, there are many other open source or commercial tools available.Twitter typeahead is probably the most important open source alternative.".replace(/source/g,function(m) { count++; return '<b>source</b>';}); 

// demo check
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = "Result: " + res;
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "<br/>Count: " + count;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```