# OrientDB count phrase in field

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

How can I count a phrase instances in a field using OrientDB?

Let's say I have the following data:

> Display_title  | Description
>   My_data_12     | The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   My_data_13     | The one

How can I count the number of 'the' instances, output similar to this:

> Display_title | Count
>   My_data_12    | 2
>   My_data_13    | 1

Comment: if you are using java this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Comment: @IvanMainetti thanks but I'm looking for OrientDB SQL query/function, not using external language or module for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using @Vitim.us answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

[image: screenshot]

you can call it from studio with

```
select title, occurrences(@this.description, "the") from v
```

NOTE that this is case sensitive, so with your example you'll get:

```
 title      | occurrences
 My_data_12 | 1
 My_data_13 | 0
```