# Search occurences of a character in the text given by the user

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I have this assignment for school and it really looks simple because the instructions are given, but I am having trouble solving it. Nothing gets displayed on my web page after pressing the search button.

Here it is:

> Write a JavaScript script called "CharacterOccurences.JS” that inputs several lines of text and a search character and uses String method indexOf() to determine the number of occurrences of the character in text.
>
> A) You have to use the external CSS file called "CharacterOccurences.CSS" to set the margin of the paragraph to the value 0 (zero).
>
> B) You have to declare in your HTML form four (04) ids:
>   a. "searchString" as textarea id in paragraph with 4 rows and 55 columns
>   b. "characters" as input id in paragraph with text type and size equal 5
>   c. "searchButton" as input id in paragraph with button type and its value
> equal "Search"
>   d. "output" as id in paragraph is for the final result.
>
> C) The JavaScript file (CharacterOccurences.js) contains three (03) global variables and two (02) functions:
>
> a. Global variables :
>
> i. searchStr to get the id of "searchString"
>       ii. ch to get the id of "characters"
>       iii. outResult to get the id of "output"
>   b. The function getAllDomElement() that
>       i. Accesses the "searchButton" element and adds the search button using its id by using the existing the function addEventListener(), which takes three (03) arguments: (a) the name of event as a string literal (here is "click"),   (b) the function searchOccurrences, and (c) the Boolean value false.
>
> ii. Gets all id elements of "searchString", "characters", "output" using the existing function getElementById()
>
> c. The function searchOccurrences() to search the character we look for and count the number of occurrences of that character.
>
> i. 4 local variables: count, chValue, searchStr, result.
>
> ii. Use the functions: charAt( 0 ), toLowerCase() and indexOf().
>
> iii. If the variable count equal 0 (zero) display the message: the character ch not found. Otherwise display the result.
>
> D) At the end of the JavaScript file, finish with this line to fire the load event when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading:
>     window.addEventListener( "load", getAllDomElement, false );

Here is my script in the html and js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title> Assignment3Q1 </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "CharacterOccurences.js">
    </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CharacterOccurences.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Enter some text: <br>
        <textarea id = "searchString" rows = "4" cols = "55"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p> Enter characters to search for: <br>
        <input type = "text" id = "characters" size = "5" />
        <input type = "button" id = "searchButton" value = "Search" onclick = "getAllDomElement();"/>
    </p>
    <p id = "output">
    </p>
</body>
```

```
searchStr = document.getElementById("searchStr");
ch = document.getElementById("characters");
outResult = document.getElementById("output");

function getAllDomElement()
{
    document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", searchOccurences, false);
    searchStr = document.getElementById("searchStr");
    ch = document.getElementById("characters");
    outResult = document.getElementById("output");
}

function searchOccurences()
{
    var count = 0;
    var chValue = ch.chartAt(0).toLowerCase();
    var searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    var result; 
}

window.addEventListener("load", getAllDomElement, false);
```

You see that I haven't completed the `searchOccurences()` function. I attempted to go through a for loop and increment count every time I find an occurrence of the letter entered, but nothing gets displayed when I press Search. It's supposed to look like this:

[image: https://ibb.co/haRviv]

Comment: Please don't include all the instructions narrow your problem to the exact issue

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Comment: am I accessing the events properly?

Comment: Instead of trying to get everything to work at once, I'd rather split the problem into manageable bits. Try to have a button paint your background pink or something, that will fix the HTML/CSS/DOM part. Then find a proper way of counting your occurences, and only then try to put everything together.