# Javascript multiple instances of word in string

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I want my code to print out all instances of name.

```
var text = "Eric bla bla bla bla bla Eric bla bla bla Eric";
var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i<text.length;i++){
    if(text.indexOf(myName) >= 0){
                hits.push(myName);
        }
}

console.log(hits);
```

Here it prints out like 20 instances of "Eric" in array 'hits'.

How to only print 3 instances(exactly 3 is in string 'text').

Comment: The loop you're using here executes for each character in string.

Comment: `(text.match(new RegExp("\\b" + myName + "\\b", "g")) || []).length`

Comment: here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924240/938822

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.prototype.match()` function to find all instances of *search name*:

```js
var text = "Eric bla bla bla bla bla Eric bla bla bla Eric",
    myName = "Eric",
    hits = text.match(new RegExp("\\b" + myName +"\\b", "g"));

console.log(hits);
```

`\b` - points to a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

You should split have split before counting. Not the each character.

```
var arr = text.split(" ");
for(var i = 0 ; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==myName){
                hits.push(myName);
        }
}
```

Comment: This works,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Save the index you got last time and use it in subsequent calls to `indexOf` to skip that occurrence. You also don't want to loop for every character, index `indexOf` scans; this is a place where `do-while` is useful:

```js
var text = "Eric bla bla bla bla bla Eric bla bla bla Eric";
var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];
var index = -1;
do {
  index = text.indexOf(myName, index + 1);
  if (index >= 0) {
    hits.push(myName);
  }
} while (index >= 0);

console.log(hits);
```

Comment: This works,but its kinda hard for me to understand(still a beginner),answer with array.split its easier for me.Thanks!

Comment: @joki00: Fair enough. Beware that the answer using `split` will fail if Eric is followed by puncutation ("You know, Eric, you're a good bloke."). And the above will identify "Eric" even in the middle of something else ("Hi, Erica"), which could be a downside for the above (or not, depends on what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `while` loop with the position as value for checking. Then use the position as start value for the next look up.

```js
var text = "Eric bla bla bla bla bla Eric bla bla bla Eric",
    myName = "Eric",
    hits = [],
    p = text.indexOf(myName);

while (p !== -1) {
    hits.push(myName);
    p = text.indexOf(myName, p + 1);
}

console.log(hits);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below may can help you.

```
var text = "Eric bla bla bla bla bla Eric bla bla bla Eric";
var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

var lastIndex = text.indexOf(myName);
while (lastIndex !== -1) {
    hits.push(myName);
    lastIndex = text.indexOf(myName, lastIndex + myName.length);
}
console.log(hits);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it print Eric as many character are present in string including white space so, for print ing 3 element statically set limit to 3

```
 for(var i = 0 ; i<3;i++)
```

or according to your question there is total 45 character so you can use like this

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<text.length;i++)
```

Comment: *"or printing 3 element statically set limit to 3"* - The point is to count the number of times "Eric" appears in the input string. So no particular limit should be set, and the total number of characters is irrelevant.