# javascript get count of non-empty JSON subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I count the number of non-empty `dailyemails` in the following json?

```
{
   "templates":[
      {
         "id":"2c1d99d9b6b2fb417601d24c10c9b041a7d6f37b",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@aa.com",
            "aaa.aaa@gmail.com"
         ],
         "name":"Registration Report"             
      },
      {
         "id":"45s4dsf4qdgze5zef1z3e2f1zevcd5s6sdfsdfsdf",
         "dailyemails":[
         ],
         "name":"Presentation"             
      },
      {
         "id":"7d7cc642ca13cc4a998cad364dfe8e623fd95ae3",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@ss.com"
         ],
         "name":"Live Report"
      }

   ]
}
```

I am currently reading the total number of nodes `Object.keys(myArr).length`:

```
function metaInfo (id, cb){

    var URL = someURLhere
    var count = []

    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + URL+'/myFile.json', 'utf8', function   (err, data) {
        if (err) cb (err);
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var myArr = obj.nodes;
        count.push(Object.keys(myArr).length);
        cb(null, count)
    });
};
```

How can I read the number of non-empty `dailyemails`?

Comment: Probably to loop and count, but if your json is compressed, than you could look for and count  `"dailyemails":[]` - it may speed up the process (method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)).

Comment: Use `map` and `filter`, and then count the resulting length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```
var count = myArray.reduce(function(c, o) {
    return c + (o.dailyemails.length? 1: 0);
}, 0);
```

even shorter using arrow functions:

```
var count = myArray.reduce((c, o) => c + (o.dailyemails.length? 1: 0), 0);
```

Comment: You don't actually need a ternary for the short version, unary operator `+`  expression in this case will always return a number, if you use `!!`. You could also use `Math.min(1, o.dailyemails.length)`. Upvoted btw :)

Comment: yea but then we would be aggregating the lengths of the non empty arrays and not the number of non-empty arrays which is what we want

Comment: @axelduch The ternary is to check whether or not the array is empty. If I take it off then ther could be some undesired result (if the array length is 555 for example).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yup that's why I suggested either a cast to a boolean (either 0 or 1), same with min(1, 555)

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Good point! Switching the places of `1` and `0` fix the problem.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir my comment was directed towards axelduch, my apologies. But I see what you mean now.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Good coincidence. Oops! The first version is the correct one. OP said _non-empty_ not empty objects.

Comment: @axelduch with the casting part I now understand what you are saying. Although it would make it more concise I like ibrahim's method due to slightly better readability imo

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski I can only agree to that

Comment: @axelduch glad we came to a consensus :-)

Answer (score 2):

`filter` all empty values out

```
var count = obj.templates.filter(item => item.dailyemails.length).length
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating an array with `filter` and then getting the length you can also use `reduce`. This doesn't have the same overhead as `filter` because the only thing you are storing is the counter in the temporary variable `p`.

```js
var x = {
   "templates":[
      {
         "id":"2c1d99d9b6b2fb417601d24c10c9b041a7d6f37b",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@aa.com",
            "aaa.aaa@gmail.com"
         ],
         "name":"Registration Report"             
      },
      {
         "id":"45s4dsf4qdgze5zef1z3e2f1zevcd5s6sdfsdfsdf",
         "dailyemails":[
         ],
         "name":"Presentation"             
      },
      {
         "id":"7d7cc642ca13cc4a998cad364dfe8e623fd95ae3",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@ss.com"
         ],
         "name":"Live Report"
      }

   ]
}

alert(x["templates"].reduce(function(p, e)
              {
                if(e["dailyemails"].length !==0)
                    p+=1;
                return p;
              },0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of the Array `filter` method.

```js
var obj = {
   "templates":[
      {
         "id":"2c1d99d9b6b2fb417601d24c10c9b041a7d6f37b",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@aa.com",
            "aaa.aaa@gmail.com"
         ],
         "name":"Registration Report"             
      },
      {
         "id":"45s4dsf4qdgze5zef1z3e2f1zevcd5s6sdfsdfsdf",
         "dailyemails":[
         ],
         "name":"Presentation"             
      },
      {
         "id":"7d7cc642ca13cc4a998cad364dfe8e623fd95ae3",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@ss.com"
         ],
         "name":"Live Report"
      }

   ]
};

var nonEmptyDailyEmails = obj.templates.filter(x => x.dailyemails && x.dailyemails.length > 0);
var countOfnonEmptyDailyEmails = nonEmptyDailyEmails.length;
console.log(countOfnonEmptyDailyEmails);
```