# naive string matching algorithm gone wrong

Tags: javascript, algorithm, naivebayes

I am trying to implement naive search and I do not get the expected result. Can anyone point out here, what could be the possible error.

```
function naive(string, str) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= string.length - str.length; i++) {
        if (string[i] == str[0]) {
            let counter = 1

            for (let j = 1; j <= str.length; j++) {
                if (string[i + j] == str[j]) {
                    counter++;
                    console.log(counter)
                } else
                    counter = 0;
            }

            if (counter == str.length) {
                console.log(`${counter} pattern matched at ${i}`)
            }
        } else
            console.log('nothing matched')
    }
}
```

Comment: Is what you want counting the number of occurences of a pattern in a string?

Comment: yes exactly, I want it to print a message in console, everytime it comes across such patterb

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string) to count occurences using regex in 2 lines

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function - what example arguments do you pass, what result did you expect to get, and what did happen instead?

Comment: Thanks @Baboo_ I am practicing basics of computer science and you pointed out a new thing(atleast for me).

Comment: Bergi I was implementing this in console of chrome :p and tested with some basic examples ('mayankananan', 'an'), I understood my mistake now. Thanks for asling though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var match_found = false;
function naive(string, str){
  for(let i =0; i <= string.length - str.length; i++){
      if(string[i] == str[0]){
        let counter= 1
            for(let j = 1; j < str.length; j++){
                if(string[i + j] == str[j]){    
                  counter++;
                }else{
                  break;
                }
            }
        if(counter == str.length){ 
          console.log('Pattern matched at ' + i);
          match_found = true;// can break; here if you wish to, else it will give you all matches present
        }
      }
  }
  if(match_found === false){
    console.log(str + ' not found in ' + string);
  }
}

naive('abcdgggabcdggg','ggg');
```

- You `increment` the `counter` when there is a match, but you need to `break` the loop where there is a `mismatch`.
- Your inner for loop condition needs to have `j < str.length` instead of `j <= str.length`, because index starts from `0`.
- `else console.log('nothing matched')`. You can't `just instantly` decide that. If a string index doesn't match, you need to still keep looking for the rest of the indexes.
  Best way to go about it is to maintain a boolean flag for it as shown in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all that iteration and comparison by yourself. Here's a simpler version of your function:

```js
function naive(string, str) {
  var counter = 0, 
    i = string.indexOf(str, 0);  //find first occurance of str in string

  while(i !== -1){
    ++counter;  //we have a match, count one up
    console.log(`counter %i, index %i`, counter, i);
    i = string.indexOf(str, i+1);  //find next occurance 
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log("result", naive("lorem upsum", "m"));
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is a simpler approach. I still have a question, Under the hood indexOf also does the same?

Comment: @MayankNauriyal I'd assume that it uses a more sophisticated algorithm, but It produces the same results.