# Using JavaScript, How to get a Y-letter count from a sentence X number of times?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a little tool that when a user enters a sentence, and then a specify letter, it takes that letter and counts it in the sentence above entered by the user and displays the number of times the letter appears in the sentence.

```js
let sentence = document.getElementById("textbox1")
let character = sentence.value
let letter = document.getElementById("textbox2")
let getLetter = letter.value
var exampleString = character
document.getElementById("parseString").onclick = letterCount;
function letterCount(string, letter, caseSensitive) {
  var count = 0;
  if (!caseSensitive) {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
  }
  for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    if (string[i] === letter) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
let display = (letterCount(character, getLetter, true));
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML
```

```html
<p>Enter a sentence: <input type="text" id="textbox1"></p>
<p>Enter a letter: <input type="text" id="textbox2"></p>
<button id="parseString">Parse String</button>
<p id="output1">The letter appears in the string</p>
```

I'm still new to JavaScript and still learning how to code and nest certain things properly.

Comment: Can you fix your snippet so that it runs? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Comment: The code seems to be working, maybe it's a little ugly and it could use some cleanup, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ChatterOne my question is how can I so that when a user enters a sentence lets say "StackOverflow" and then enters "o" in the 2nd textbox, and the output shows "The letter O appears 2 times"

Comment: @CertainPerformance will update now.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string

Comment: @C.Gibby theirs is using a string but I would like it to get the value from textbox1 that the user enters a sentence

Comment: @MichaelKheong You should be able to use sentence.value to get the textbox value in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up your code, Some of the variables in top must be inside your event handler

```js
document.getElementById("parseString").onclick = function() {
  let character = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
  let getLetter = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
  let count = letterCount(character, getLetter, true);
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = `The letter '${getLetter}' appears in the string '${character}' ${count} times`;
}

function letterCount(string, letter, caseSensitive) {
    regexp = caseSensitive ? new RegExp(letter, 'g') : new RegExp(letter, 'gi');
    return string.match(regexp).length;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a sentence: <input type="text" id="textbox1"></p>
<p>Enter a letter: <input type="text" id="textbox2"></p>
<button id="parseString">Parse String</button>
<p id="output1">The letter appears in the string</p>
```

Comment: I'd at least add a `;` to the line endings (quite a few are missing), also `exampleString` is never used