# How to check how many times a word shows up in JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js

My JSON array looks like this:

```
    {
  "messages": [
    {
      "msg": "?",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello",
      "name": "johndoe",
    },
    {
      "msg": "twitt",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello everyone!",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello! how are you",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      .........
```

I would like to know how I can check how many times the word "hello" shows up in this whole array, and then just return the number. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = {
  "messages": [{
      "msg": "?",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello",
      "name": "johndoe",
    },
    {
      "msg": "twitt",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello everyone!",
      "name": "johndoe!!"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello! how are you",
      "name": "johndoe!"
    }
  ]
};

const count = arr.messages.reduce((acc, m) => {
  if (m.name === "johndoe") {
    acc += 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(count)

//shorter version
const count2 = arr.messages.reduce((acc, m) => m.name === "johndoe" ? acc += 1 : acc, 0);
console.log(count2)


// EDIT : if you wanna search for "johndoe" string and the name value is "johndoe!!"
const count3 = arr.messages.reduce((acc, m) => {
  if (m.name.includes("johndoe")) {
    acc += 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(count3)
```

Comment: is there a way to make this so that "m.name" will add 'acc' variable by 1 even if the name is "johndoe 123", "johndoe", and "johndoe!" ? So that it doesn't specifically check for the object that only has the name "johndoe" and there is more flexibility

Answer (score 2):

```
let helloCount = data.messages.filter(message=>{return message.msg.includes('hello')}).length;
```

Try above one

Answer (score 1):

You need the following.

```
data.forEach(ele => {if(ele.msg.includes('hello')) counter++ });
```

Here is a demo https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3v2spaetr

Answer (score 0):

Since it it's a valid JSON format it may as well be treated as a string (before parsing) if that's the case a simple regex would be enough to count the occurrences of particular string inside of it

```js
const input = `{
  "messages": [
    {
      "msg": "?",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello",
      "name": "johndoe",
    },
    {
      "msg": "twitt",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello everyone!",
      "name": "johndoe"
    },
    {
      "msg": "hello! how are you",
      "name": "johndoe"
    }
  ]
}`;

function count(input, match){
  return (input.match(new RegExp(match, "g")) || []).length;
}

console.log("hello: ", count(input, "hello"));
console.log("johndoe: ", count(input, "johndoe"));
```