# count variable substring inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a string in javascript like this:

```
var stringa = 'CONCATENATE("custom text 1", CHAR(10), "text", CHAR(10), "other text", CHAR(10), "another one", CHAR(10), "funny last string")';
```

My goal is to count the substring inside the string, splitted by `,`, excluding CHAR(10). The constant rule is: substring I need to count are inside `" "` so in my example there are 5 substring.

How can I do it only using javascript or jquery?

I've found this solution but I think is there is a more elegant way:

```
var total = stringa.match(/\"/g) || []).length / 2;
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's best if you can show [any research you've done](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: You could split on `"` get length of returned array - 1 and divide by 2...

Comment: You need only count or values of substrings?

Comment: @HereticMonkey added solution not very elegant I think..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: @brso05 yes I've done this see my update.

Comment: @AnatoliiParubets i need only count occurrencies of a value inside " .. "

Comment: "Elegance" is a very subjective measurement. One person's elegant is another's confusing unmaintainable spaghetti.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini why do u want a "more elegant way" your code is one line of code???

Answer (score 1):

You could split on `"` get length of returned array - 1 and divide by 2...

```js
var stringa = 'CONCATENATE("custom text 1", CHAR(10), "text", CHAR(10), "other text", CHAR(10), "another one", CHAR(10), "funny last string")';

var temp = stringa.split('"');
var count = (temp.length - 1) / 2;
window.alert(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` for that:

```js
var stringa = 'CONCATENATE("custom text 1", CHAR(10), "text", CHAR(10), "other text", CHAR(10), "another one", CHAR(10), "funny last string")';

var matches = stringa.match(/"([^"]+)"/g) || [];
console.log(matches);
var count = matches.length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Oh, you've updated the question. Well, then I think there's nothing wrong with the regex approach