# Bean Counting WITHOUT using for loop and regex

Tags: javascript, recursion, count

I tried to solve the following problem without using the for loop:

> "Write a function countBs that takes a string as its only argument and returns a number that indicates how many uppercase “B” characters there are in the string.
> `console.log(countBs("BBC")); // → 2`

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code I wrote so far which doesn't work:

```js
function countBs(word) {
  let count = 0
  if (word.length == 0) {
    return count;
  } else {
    if (word[word.length - 1] == 'B') {
      count++
    }
    return countBs(word.slice(0, word.length - 1))
  }
}
console.log(countBs("BBC"))
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use recursion for this, or why this approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: `return count + countBs(word.slice(0, word.length - 1));`

Comment: @CBroe I was just trying to understand if recursion can be used for this without using for loop or regex.

Comment: @Argee no it seems not. Thank you though.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you for your reply. I tried to implement but it still returns undefined.

Comment: Sure recursion _could_ be used here - but it has little advantage over a simple loop. If anything, it has disadvantages, due to the call stack size recursive calls will cause.

Comment: @LucasErlacher Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ubwnvkh8/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you're right. I placed it in the wrong bracket. Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: `function countBs(word, count = 0) {
  if (word.length == 0) {
    return count;
  } else {
    if (word[word.length - 1] == 'B') {
      count++
    }
    return countBs(word.slice(0, word.length - 1), count)
  }
}
console.log(countBs("BBC"))` would be how you can modify your code...

Comment: Because a string can be destructured into an array, we can write a fairly simply recursive version: `const countBs = ([c, ...cs]) => c == undefined ? 0 : (c === 'B' ? 1 : 0) + countBs(cs)`.  We could fairly easily convert it to tail-recursive, if TCO ever becomes a JS reality.

Comment: Thank you @ScottSauyet

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use regex for this case:

```
function countBs(word) {
  const matches = word.match(/B/g);

  return matches && matches.length || 0;
}
```

Basically it `g`lobally searches for occurrences of 'B'. If it find it, it returns the length of it, if the matches are `null` it will return 0.

Simpler less expressive:

```
function countBs(word) {
  return (word.match(/B/g) || []).length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Poul for your answer. I would like to understand why my version is not working without using regex.

Comment: @LucasErlacher because you initialize the count to 0 at every iteration... if you give the current count to your function, it works well... see my comment above for reference

Comment: Thank you @Argee