# Find number of occurrences of word in the whole sentence using angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am looking for any proper solution to check number of occurrence of word in the sentences.

```js
Input:
k = 2
keywords = ["anacell", "cetracular", "betacellular"]
reviews = [
  "Anacell provides the best services in the city",
  "betacellular has awesome services",
  "Best services provided by anacell, everyone should use anacell",
]

Output:
["anacell", "betacellular"]

Explanation:
"anacell" is occuring in 2 different reviews and "betacellular" is only occuring in 1 review.

Input:
k = 2
keywords = ["anacell", "betacellular", "cetracular", "deltacellular", "eurocell"]
reviews = [
  "I love anacell Best services; Best services provided by anacell",
  "betacellular has great services",
  "deltacellular provides much better services than betacellular",
  "cetracular is worse than anacell",
  "Betacellular is better than deltacellular.",
]

Output:
["betacellular", "anacell"]

Explanation:
"betacellular" is occuring in 3 different reviews. "anacell" and "deltacellular" are occuring in 2 reviews, but "anacell" is lexicographically smaller.
```

based on the keywords value i would like to check their occurrences in the reviews array and want to display the numbers based on which keyword occured more.

Comment: I don't understand the question...what is the connection between the input and the output?

Comment: updated question with one more example.. input k will define how many values comes in output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: Updated my answer to count only reviews instead of keyword occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

```
countKeywords(keywords: string[], reviews: string[]) => {
    let result = [];

    keywords.forEach(key => {
        let data = {};
        data.keyword = key;
        data.review_count = 0;

        reviews.forEach(review => {
            if (review.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())) {
                data.review_count += 1;
            }
        })

        result.push(data);
    })

    return result;
}
```

Returns an Object Array with corresponding values.

[image]

Comment: You can then perform any sorting or filtering on the array based on key value pairs.

Comment: if i pass only anacell and batacellular it will show 2 values in array right?

Comment: Correct. The function is data agnostic and will output values based only on what you put in. Which makes the function reusable.

Comment: @jamesmallred, Can you review my updated answer for sort and spice?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code to find the number of occurrences of the keywords.

```
let map:any
this.keywords.forEach((keyword)=>
{
  let temp=0;
 this.reviews.forEach((review)=>{
   if(review.indexOf(keyword)>-1){
     temp++
    }
 });
  map[keyword]=temp
})

console.log(map['anacell'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const keywords = ["anacell", "cetracular", "betacellular"];
const reviews = [
    "Anacell provides the best services in the city",
    "betacellular has awesome services",
    "Best services provided by anacell, everyone should use anacell",
];

let occurences = [];
for (const kw of keywords)
    for (const rw of reviews) {
        const lower = rw.toLowerCase();
        const lower2 = kw.toLowerCase();
        if (occurences.indexOf(lower2) < 0 && lower.indexOf(lower2) >= 0)
            occurences.push(kw);
    }
console.log(occurences);
```

Answer (score 1):

used jamesmallred to update sorting and splice methods.

```js
countKeywords(keywords: string[], reviews: string[]) => {
    let result = [];

    keywords.forEach(key => {
        let data = {};
        data.keyword = key;
        data.count = 0;

        reviews.forEach(review => {
            if (review.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())) {
                data.count += 1;
            }
        })

        result.push(data);
    })

    return result;
}

//sorting 

 result.sort((a,b) => {
            if(b.keyword === a.keyword) {
                return a.keyword.localeCompare(b.keyword); // if equal - sort alphabetically
            }
            else {
                return b.keyword  - a.keyword  // we want to sort from highest to low 
            }

        });
        
        
//splice based on the input

result.splice(0,k);
```

Comment: For this instance, you would want to sort recursively kinda like I processed the data. The first sort to sort based on review count and then another sort to alphabetize the keywords if the review count was equal. I also don’t think the splice is necessary.

Comment: I have added splice as bravo mentioned k =2 means based on k it will show the most higher number of data which is mentioned in example 2 of question.

Comment: In example 2 output , there are only 2 data based on higher to lower as well as Alphabetic order ( if same size) as k=2 mentioned in input. @bravo correct me if I am wrong