# How can I connect google sheets with google calendar using only one cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to connect my google sheets to google calendar.
The thing is:
I have multiple movies that are going to release in the future and I want to have them in my google calendar. The problem is that these movies are releasing in multiple regions and I need different calendars for every region (LATAM, Caribe and Brazil).
Just to let you know, I cannot separate them into different rows.
Also, I would like the calendar to update automatically if possible.
[image]

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("622671516d6be59ea9b3160169be6a0bc330b0ea21a453f9be2670fca70eea2f@group.calendar.google.com");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,2);

  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
  communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[1], entry[0], entry[0]);
});
}
```

I know this is not 100% right considering I have to use "if" however, I don't know what to do with the regions thing.
Please help me.

Comment: Your data show the region with 3 values. Is there any other case?

Comment: Hi @CharlesHan yes, I know. Most of the time it's going to be the 3 regions. That's why I'm lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)